# Alternative phrase/term for 'middle men'

Tags: phrase-requests

I head up a support team.

In some situations I refer to some issues where support act as 'middle men' between the clients and the developers.

This seems sexist (females in the team), but I cannot find a better term.
Any ideas?

Comment: There's always the _politically-corrected_ "middle people," but that might offend some men.  =(

Comment: I did try writing that, but didnt have the right ring.  go-between works for my scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most literal synonym is *[go-between](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/go-between?region=us)*. A better and more formal-sounding term would be *[intermediary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/intermediary?region=us)*.

Answer (score 2):

Intermediaries might be the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An existing answer suggests *go-between* or *intermediary* and I up-voted that because I'd lean towards *intermediary* myself.  However, I would also suggest:

- *[liaison](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/liaison)*

I have a few more, with similar meanings but different connotations, for others who might ask the same question with different goals:

- *[agent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/agent)*
- *[representative](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/representative)*
- *[front line](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/front-line)* or *first line of defense*
- *[buffer](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/buffer)* (somewhat condescending, but accurate)
- *[envoy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/envoy)*